# Is it acceptable to use the word order of a question in a declarative sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order

I pretty often hear native German speakers using the word order of a question in a declarative sentence.

E.g.

> Habe ich doch gesagt!

or

> Habe ich kein Problem damit.

Is this an acceptable form, or are those people just unaware of the grammar?

---

### Update

The last sentence is an example I heard just today (not for the first time however). The whole (spoken) conversation did look like:

> -- Wenn du nicht aufpasst, ist dein Glas schnell weg.
>   -- Habe ich kein Problem damit.

Comment: It works very similar to the English "Told you so." ["Habe ich doch gesagt" is not derived from the word order of a question, but by ellipsis from the declarative sentence "Das habe ich doch gesagt."]. Very acceptable in colloquial speech, not acceptable in written texts.

Comment: I'm not convinced, that the examples address the same issue. In the first example just a leading *Das* is omitted, in the second may be a leading *Da*.

Comment: The first sentence is very common. But I've never heard the second one. "Damit habe ich kein Problem" is what people usually say.

Comment: @em1, see my update. It's not the first time that I've heard such a sentence. Perhaps this is more common in the southern regions, could it be?

Comment: I think the second one more often is: _»Hab ich kein Problem mit.«_

Comment: @Pollitzer True. And then it's like the first one, with the initial word omitted.

Comment: There is no proofreading in speech. Mixing up two independently correct variations of a sentence into one incorrect one does happen occasionally.

Comment: Gut feeling re. the discussion about the second example sentence: "... **mit**" sounds "northern", "... **damit**" sounds "southern" to me. I'd expect my Swabian colleagues to use the latter, those from further north to use the former.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are colloquial sentences and actually omit the first part of the sentence. If you add the missing part in your mind – which the native speaker will do automatically – you get the verb in the second position, as you would expect for a main clause.

> [Das] habe ich doch gesagt!
>
> [Da] habe ich kein Problem damit.

Note that both your example sentences are idiomatic, but especially the latter is informal, bordering on sloppy.